# Where can we find M2 (or M1) data breakdown by wealth percentiles?

Tags: reference-request, money-supply, wealth

(this question refers to the US only)

We have [official data on M2](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/M2SL) by the Fed, but, if I understand correctly, this M2 data includes even bank deposits of firms/corporations where I am after the households.

In particular, I'm looking of M2 data by groups like wealth percentiles. We can see again from the Fed very nice tables and graphs on [Distribution of Household Wealth](https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/z1/dataviz/dfa/distribute/chart/)  that allow you to have those kind of queries. In the "Assets" we can find: Real estate, consumer durable goods, corporate equities and mutual found shares, pensions, private businesses or "other assets".

What I seek is basically bank deposits and saving accounts, I'm not sure this is what "other assets" stands for here. Where can I find this kind of information? Thanks.

Comment: That sort of statistics does not exist because M2 is macro variable and by the way it does not consist just of deposits but also coins and notes in circulation and things like cheques and clearly it’s impossible to figure out how much quarters or notes or cheques a rich person has. There are statistics on wealth inequality that tell you wealth/income distribution but I don’t think it’s even possible to calculate M2 money holding distribution across household as data for it are not even collected by anyone. Also what is your goal actually a reason why these data are not collected is that

Comment: m2 holding is not considered relevant when we talk about let’s say wealth inequality because for that total assets matter not just notes someone has

Comment: @1muflon1, thanks. I'm not specifically after M2 neither seek accuracy. Fed already provides some interesting stats like I said durable goods, equities  etc. I don't know what is there methodology to have those, but whatever it is I would think it is also possible to estimate what are the liquid financial assets of those. But you may be right indeed. At any case, any information of M2 that of households will be appreciated even without breakdown to wealth percentiles (As I said the I believe the official M2 number includes companies balances etc.)

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging, I've found some Fed series that are relevant:

[Households; Checkable Deposits](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/BOGZ1FL193020005Q) ( [bottom 50%](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/WFRBLB50086), [50-90%](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/WFRBLN40059), [90-99%](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/WFRBLN09032), [99-100%](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/WFRBLT01005));;; in general the series are all in this [neat table](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/release/tables?rid=453&eid=813668#snid=813697) it includes saving/time deposits and MMF deposits. together they are good approximation for M2

Comment: I don't suppose you had just been watching this video... See 20mins and 50 seconds into this -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1xgQeCiu6k

Comment: @Mick, interesting! I had in mind the impact of the CPI and money velocity so I wanted to check some things out. FWIW, I don't agree with his main thesis if I got that right (started from 22:50) but that's another story. thanks for sharing.